# ODBC Data Sources; can't add MySQL Driver

Tags: mysql, sql-server, odbc, ms-access-2010

I want to connect MS Access with MySQL. I installed Xampp for MySQL and now I installed the ODBC driver 5.3. I went to Data Sources and clicked on System-DSN to add the MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver (like shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F06hvR6ksh4). But there wasn't any MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver. 
My OS is Windows 7 Home x64. How can I connect the ODBC Driver to the MySQL Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to use 32bit MySQL ODBC connector on 64bit Windows, you need to 
use 32bit Data Sources (c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe).

Answer (score 0):

You might haven't installed ODBC Connector for MySQL yet.
Install it first then add MySQL to the ODBC.
Check here for the connector you need http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/

Comment: That's the one I installed. Connector/ODBC 5.3.4

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the older version and it worked.